# When I merge two tables in PowerBI, why does not all rows gets matched even though the correlation exists?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have two tables that I'm merging in the Power Query editor in Power BI. One very small table (A) with just 8k rows that should merge with another table (B) with roughly 220k rows. The idea is to just get the information from the table (B) about the rows in the Table (A).

The tables should be merged using a common column with a "Text" data type, both columns are already trimmed, cleaned and are all lowercase. Also the rows in the table (A) are not unique, they are unique on the table (B).

The result table after the merge, just misses merging information for about 4k (out of 8k) rows in the table (A) even though they exists in the table (B).

I tried the same operation using the Power Query tool in Excel and it did work perfectly.

Do you know why it is not working as it should in Power BI?

Comment: Try to regenerate the same with 5 to 10 rows in each table and share that sample dataset with the output. This will make things easier to understand :)

Comment: This can't be solved by pure thinking.

Comment: Perhaps you could share the 3 things or so I should check in my process?

Comment: You've already done the 3 things (trimming, cleaning, and all lowercase).  The next thing produce and share a short repro as suggested by @mkRabbani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue with merging in Power BI's Power Query was solved by a simple system reboot.

I usually work with tools like DBeaver, Visual Studio Code, Power BI and Excel and obviously by the time I was writing this question they were all open in my laptop.

For no reason I just decided to reboot my laptop and after that, my Power BI file just did work as it should. I'm used to shutdown my laptop everyday.

I have a big question mark in my head right now, but the issue is solved.